# sass - Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - style.css

Tags: sass

I have been using sass without issue until I installed the rails installer and now I am getting this error;

[image]

Can someone explain this message to me... thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the the backtrace? Also, what version of Sass and Rails are you running?

Comment: i edited the post with another screen shot

Comment: the trace does nothing

Comment: To get trace information, re-run the previous command (`sass --watch ...`) with an additional `--trace` at the end of it. Ex: `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed -- trace`.

Comment: trace is up... thanks for the help btw